# How to get the canvas items that have some tags?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I would like to know if theres a way to get all the items in the canvas that contain the tags. As far as I know the function `canvas.find_withtag(tag)` only allows for one tag and I would like to be able to do: `canvas.find_withtag(tag0, tag1, ...)`. Basically is there a clean way to get the items that match more than one tag without having to play with sets. Is there a clean way or will I have to do the logic myself using canvas.find_withtag(tag)?

What Im actually asking is if theres is a better way to accomplish this:

```py
itemstag1 = set(self.v_maps.canvas.find_withtag(tag1))
itemstag2 = set(self.v_maps.canvas.find_withtag(tag2))
for item in itemstag1 &itemstag2:
    self.canvas.itemconfig(item, fill=color)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `canvas.find_withtag('tag1||tag2')`.

From the tk [document](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm):

> tagOrId may contain a logical expressions of tags by using operators: “&&”, “||”, “^”, “!”, and parenthesized subexpressions.

Comment: @Daniel: Here's some Python documentation on the [`Canvas.find_withtag()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190530082613id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html) method (and others).

Comment: Okey I understand now. Thanks